# White space on the right side from mobile

Tags: android, jquery, html, ios, css

I know tons of people are talking about it, but I still can't get out.
I have a mobile-oriented web page  and I'm still trying to remove the white space on the right.

I partially solved it on iOS thanks to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
```

and

```
    html,body
    {
        width:100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow-x:hidden;
    }
```

but on Android it happens almost always. Although overflow-x is hidden, in fact, if I start to scroll down and then drag left, the white space is there.

And it also becames visible if I start dragging left from the extreme right of the screen, as if I wanted to show the scrollbar.

I think I have to solve it with @meta tag in the CSS, but I don't know how to start.
Can somebody give me some hint?

Unfortunately I can't share the whole code due to society's policy.

Thanks to all of you.

Comment: Consider switching `width: 100%;` to `width: auto;` as per [this blog post explanation](http://headertofooter.com/post/80699461723/the-difference-between-width-auto-and-width-100)

Comment: This may happened due to wide no of reasons. One way to debug is on page comment one by one piece of code like header, main content, sidebar etc and check on mobile then you may find which piece of code giving trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect Android device into computer and inspect page. Have you tried this? For me it is the easiest way to find this kind of bugs.

Comment: I am curious! but how can mobile browsers screen can be inspected on computer can you explain more about it please

Comment: Sure. You must open a page on your mobile phone, connect yours phone with computer and install [this plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adb/dpngiggdglpdnjdoaefidgiigpemgage) for Chrome. Then you lunch the plugin and that's all - you can inspect webpages opened on your phone. It looks like on the third photo.

Comment: I set your answer as the correct one because it was what helped me most.
I knew about the USB debugging, but hadn't realized it showed me all the HTML elements on the phone.

The white border was caused by a overflow:visible on a span I hadn't noticed.
Now I really hate people who wrote that CSS.